# Pandas Count certain Value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-wrangling

I have follwing dataframe:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0,0,0 |
| 4 | 2,0,2 |
| 56 | 1 |
| 75 | 2,0 |
| 52 | 0,0,0 |

How can I count the Total Number of `0,0,0` in column **B**? In my example above it would be: 2

Thank you!!!

Comment: `df['B'].eq('0,0,0').sum()`? assuming column B is a string

Comment: Your column B is string or lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column 'B' consists of lists then this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({'A': [3,4,56,75,52],'B': [[0,0,0],[2,0,2],[1],[2,0],[0,0,0]]})

listWeSearch = [0,0,0]
counter = 0

counter = len([counter+1 for i in range(len(df)) if df.iloc[i]['B'] == listWeSearch])
```

Otherwise if the values of 'B' the other solutions proposed should work!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
count = df.B[df.B.apply(lambda x : str(x).strip() == "0,0,0")].size
```